# How to start multi panel with one command

Tags: tmux

I'm new to tmux and lately I'm thinking about how to start multi panels with just one command.
For example, 4 panels with one command. And I can do this by typing [Ctrl-b + "] and [Ctrl-b + %]. I wonder is there any less typing way?
Any answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you often need a new 2x2 panes tmux session, you could make a shell alias to the following command:

```
tmux new -s '2x2 panes' \; split-window -h \; split-window -v \; select-pane -t 0 \; split-window -v \; attach
```